# How to create a half circle donut chart in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Please let me know, how to create a half circle donut chart in Tableau. Please see the attached image.
Lables can be fine with inside donut/outside of donut.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is possible, but not really easy. At least, not a beginner task. People do it. You'd probably use a polygon mark type and have to do some trig calcs and data padding. A full circle donut chart is very simple by comparison.

Comment: Alex, Please let me know if you find a solution for it.

Comment: I recommend finding a simpler design if you are new to Tableau. But if you are set on a half donut, you'll need to learn some of the trickier parts of Tableau and put in some work. That effort may pay off long term. A good place to start is https://youtu.be/myyakEnuqa8  and then learn table calcs and data densification. Or you can make a full donut and hide the bottom as @unni_ukmv suggests. If you are in hurry, I'd try that first

Comment: Thanks Alex,
It helps me in short term way, whereas, we need to figure it out for a permanent solution as you suggested in your above comment like using trig calcs & data padding. Hope it would be best solution for us. Thanks.!

Comment: Alex, I really thanks to you for sharing the wonderful knowledge "A good place to start is youtu.be/myyakEnuqa8 and then learn table calcs and data densification. "

I was really scared about these trig cals & x,y calcs, now I can learn and explore more related data densification charts.

Hope, D3js.org is the best site for learn many charts to densification charts. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy method to do this. Basically it is a tweek in full donut chart. We will create a full donut chart and hiding the bottom half.

See details in : https://rahulsblogorg.wordpress.com/2017/06/08/creating-a-semi-circle-donut-an-extension-of-donut-chart/

Comment: Thanks Unni, I tried that, but in my case it didn't work for me.  Can try once and let me know. https://public.tableau.com/views/Pending_HalfCircleDonutChartinTableau/Sheet1?:display_count=y&:origin=viz_share_link

Comment: As Alex suggested in above, if we need that into dynamic way, there is a lot of workaround will be involved.  Eg:-  https://youtu.be/gUv2QTZamK4

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but thought I'd respond in case others find this in the future. One issue with the solution posted above is that the half donut will never be quite horizontal--because of the way pie charts are created (starting at the top and moving clockwise), this approach will always have issues. The only way I've found to create this chart is using polygons. Here's a blog on the topic: [Half Donut Chart in Tableau](https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2022/12/half-donut.html)